# Substitute strings by their first match in a dictionary

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a vector `long_strings` defined as

```
long_strings <- c("*/1/1/1/1", "*/1/2/1/1", "*/2/1",
                "*/2/2/1", "*/3/1/1/1")
```

and I have a dictionary of short `short_strings` containing the initial patterns (with differing lengths) of those strings, for example

```
short_strings <- c("*/1/1", "*/3", "*/2", "*/1/2")
```

How can I "simplify" the contents of `long_strings` to match their corresponding value on `short_strings`?

The results should look like

```
"*/1/1", "*/1/2", "*/2", "*/2", "*/3"
```

I can find where are the occurrences of a single element of `short_strings` using `grep("\\*/2", long_strings)`, but I want to avoid looping over the `short_strings`.

Comment: May be `stack(sapply(setNames(paste0("\\", short_strings), short_strings), grep, x = long_strings))[,2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option with `sapply`

```
as.character(with(stack(sapply(setNames(paste0("\\", short_strings), short_strings),
     grep, x = long_strings)), ind[order(values)]))
#[1] "*/1/1" "*/1/2" "*/2"   "*/2"   "*/3"
```

---

Or using `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(long_strings, str_c(str_c("\\", short_strings), collapse="|"))
#[1] "*/1/1" "*/1/2" "*/2"   "*/2"   "*/3"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can programmatically create a capture group and use it in `sub` to extract it

```
sub(paste0(".*(",paste0("\\", short_strings, collapse = "|"), ").*"), "\\1",long_strings)
#[1] "*/1/1" "*/1/2" "*/2"   "*/2"   "*/3"
```